# length can't be less than zero

Tags: vb.net, outofrangeexception

I'm receiving the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.

This is the code producing the error:

```
'Parse coordinate string into coordinate values (degrees, minutes, seconds)
'Degrees
StartPtr = 0
StopPtr = DegreeString.IndexOf("°", StartPtr)
Degrees = Convert.ToDouble(DegreeString.Substring(StartPtr, StopPtr - StartPtr))
```

The error comes in the Degrees line and tells me my StopPtr is returning -1.

Comment: Please read through [ask], and then see here to learn how to create a [mcve]. You've just dumped a ton of code with a vague *I can't really figure this out* sentence.

Comment: I went back and adjusted the question some and took some of the coding out.  I'm hoping I left enough for people to understand what the program is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Substring(startIndex, length)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) function is complaining that you passed a negative number as the `length` parameter. Which is invalid for obvious reasons (right?).

This means that `StopPtr - StartPtr` must be evaluating to something less than zero. You know `StartPtr` is exactly zero, because you just set it to zero. So `StopPtr` must be less than zero.

So that means `DegreeString.IndexOf("°", StartPtr)` is returning a negative number.

The [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) function returns -1 when the substring is not found.

So the problem must be that `DegreeString` does not contain the character `"°"`.

Comment: I understand what your saying with indexOf returning -1.  I was attempting to change: StartPtr = 0
        StopPtr = Hubs(Index1Integer).Lat.IndexOf("°", StartPtr)
        degrees = Convert.ToDouble(Hubs(Index1Integer).Lat.Substring(StartPtr, StopPtr - StartPtr)) into the function above with the DegreeString being my input parameter.  I'm confused with how it would be out of OutOfRange now.

Comment: @MARQUEBURGESS - It's because `DegreeString` does not contain `'°'`. That's the only reason.

Comment: In order to understand what's happening, you need to set some breakpoints in your code and step through it, observing how the values of your variables change as the code executes.

Comment: Sorry.  I went through it and understand what you guys are saying.  I was looking right past it.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it.